# How to fillter the database null values of integer column in C# using if condition?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am passing data value, to a database, using integer data type (accepting `null`).

If in front-end I do not pass any integer it takes `null` value in db. While retrieving table data in front-end I am using `if` condition to filter the integer empty values. I have only integers to display, how to write the if condition?

```
int x;
if(x!=(which code this place write)
{
textbox.text=x; //x value not empty working if condition else goto else condition
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: what if condition you have tried?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Edit your post and add code.

Comment: Why use if and not LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (dt.Rows[0]["ToAge"] == DBNull.Value)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question but I guess you want to use [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)

ex:

```
if(your value == System.DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Entity Framework ,you could use

> if(yourvalue.HasValue){ ...}

Comment: It is not working for integers. Integers has not "HasValue" property